# How to rename a DjangoCMS's plugin?

Tags: django-cms

I can't find information on how to change a DjangoCMS's plugin name.

I've already renamed the model behind the plugin. But now I want to change the plugin name to something else. But since it is used many times in current data, I seek for a reliable way to do it.
Particularly which queries are required to perform in database during in migrations.

For now I've only found that changing `plugin_type` in CMSPlugin objects seems to work. But I wonder if there is other locations to perform a change.

```py
CMSPlugin.objects.filter(plugin_type='OldMyPlugin').update(plugin_type='NewMyPlugin')
```

Thanks

Comment: I think this should be sufficient.

Comment: Yakki created a [post](https://dev.to/yakky/converting-a-django-cms-plugin-to-a-different-model-2h13) on dev.to, explaining how to "Convert a django CMS plugin to a different model". I think that moving your plugins data from your old djangocms plugin (with the old name) to the new djangocms plugin (with the new name) is similar.